# What temperament do Hang drums/hand pans use

Tags: percussion, temperament

Do they use just, equal, or some other tuning system?

Comment: Take care with the 'drum' part! The inventors take a dim view of it being called a drum -it actually isn't. Not even a hand-pan...

Comment: The Wikipedia page is pretty detailed about the many different tunings and controllable variants produced.

Answer (score 1):

A Google found 'Didgeproject' about Hangs - which can come tuned in different ways. major, minor scales, so I guess, at the price they are, the purchaser could specify exactly what tuning they wanted. Not sure if Hangs (originals) are still made - other companies have copied the idea, though.